# Finding an intersection with respect to the decoration

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations, intersections

in 
[Naming nodes in a decoration and draw lines from node to node](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/461118/naming-nodes-in-a-decoration-and-draw-lines-from-node-to-node/461136?noredirect=1#comment1160049_461136)
I asked a question, which was answered. The most help was the following.

```
    \documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    decoration={
    markings,
    mark=at position 0.4 with {\draw[->] (0,0)--(0,1);
    \draw[->] (0,0)--(2,-2) node[below]{A};
    \draw[<-] (0,0)--(-.8,-.8);}
    }
    ]
    \draw[postaction={decorate}] plot [smooth cycle] coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (3,1) (3,0) (2,-1)};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Now, being able to draw those lines and naming the point, the follow up question is:
Can I find the intersection of A with the smooth plot in relation to the smooth plot. I'd like the intersection in terms of pos=.3 or something, so can do a decoration at the intersection. Is it possible and how can it be done?

Thanks a lot.
Greetings
Fabian

Comment: `A` is a node. What you mean by intersection of `A` with plot?

Comment: A was the name i gave to the arrow to distinguish it. Sorry for the bad naming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is actually less innocent than it might appear to you. Luckily `pgfplots` (!) has its means to decompose a path into intersection segments, which, in turn, one can decorate. In this MWE

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[postaction={decorate,decoration={
markings,
mark=at position 0.4 with {\draw[->] (0,0)--(0,1);
\draw[->,name path=pathA] (0,0)--(2,-2) node[below]{A};
\draw[<-] (0,0)--(-.8,-.8);}
}},name path global=pathB] plot [smooth cycle] coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (3,1) (3,0) (2,-1)};
\path[ draw=blue,
    postaction={decoration={
markings,
mark=at position 1 with {\draw[->] (0,0)--(0,1);}
},decorate},
        intersection segments={of=pathA and pathB,
            sequence={R2},
        },];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I compute (and draw in blue for illustration purposes) the intersection segment to the point where the original smooth plot intersects with the line labeled `A`. This point with now have position 1 in the segment. One can then e.g. draw a normal vector at this point.

Comment: I'm always learning new features from you!

Comment: @CarLaTeX Just don't tell your doctor that you are learning things from a marmot, bad things could happen. ;-)

Comment: Lol, my ducktor!