# Tangent Lines Diagram Along Smooth Curve

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections

I am trying to replicate a diagram and have a minimal example.  I don't know how to add additional tangents between the specified points and preserve smoothness.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% Axes
\draw [->, name path=x] (-1,0) -- (11,0) node [right] {$x$};
\draw [->] (0,-1) -- (0,6) node [above] {$y$};
% Origin
\node at (0,0) [below left] {$0$};
% Points
\coordinate (start) at (1,-0.8);
\coordinate (c1) at (3,3);
\coordinate (c2) at (5.5,1.5);
\coordinate (c3) at (8,4);
\coordinate (end) at (10.5,-0.8);
% show the points
\foreach \n in {start,c1,c2,c3,end} \fill [black] (\n)
    circle (2pt) node [below] {};
% join the coordinates
\draw [thick,name path=curve] (start) to[out=70,in=180] (c1) to[out=0,in=180]
    (c2) to[out=0,in=180] (c3) to[out=0,in=150] (end);
% add tangets and dashed lines
\foreach \c in {1,2,3} {
    %\draw [dashed] let \p1=(c\c) in (c\c) -- (\x1,0) node [below] {$c_\c$};
    \draw ($(c\c)-(0.75,0)$) -- ($(c\c)+(0.75,0)$) node [midway,above=4mm]{$$}; %{$f'(c_\c)=0$};
}
% add a and b
\path [name intersections={of={x and curve}, by={a,b}}] (a) node [below left] {$a$}
    (b) node [above right] {$b$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Outputs:

[image]
My Goal is create the following:

[image]

Feel free to make any changes that make the minimal example approach the goal diagram

Comment: I sense without having a concrete equation for the graph above this will be a challenge. Unless there is another programming tool for TiKz?

Comment: Marmot mentions https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25928/how-to-draw-tangent-line-of-an-arbitrary-point-on-a-path-in-tikz/25940#25940

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a bit of calculus:

[image]

The `\DrawTangent` macro creates two vertical lines around the given x values and computes the intersection of those and the curve. Then, the tangent can be approximated by the secant between those two intersection points.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}


\newcommand*{\DeltaX}{0.01}
\newcommand*{\DrawTangent}[5][]{%
    % #1 = draw options
    % #2 = name of curve
    % #3 = ymin
    % #4 = ymax
    % #5 = x value at which tangent is to be drawn
    
    \path[name path=Vertical Line Left]  (#5-\DeltaX,#3) -- (#5-\DeltaX,#4);
    \path[name path=Vertical Line Right] (#5+\DeltaX,#3) -- (#5+\DeltaX,#4);
    
    \path [name intersections={of=Vertical Line Left and #2}];
    \coordinate (X0) at (intersection-1);
    \path [name intersections={of=Vertical Line Right and #2}];
    \coordinate (X1) at (intersection-1);
    
    \draw [shorten <= -1.00cm, shorten >= -1.00cm, #1] (X0) -- (X1);
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% Axes
\draw [->, name path=x] (-1,0) -- (11,0) node [right] {$x$};
\draw [->] (0,-1) -- (0,6) node [above] {$y$};
% Origin
\node at (0,0) [below left] {$0$};
% Points
\coordinate (start) at (1,-0.8);
\coordinate (c1) at (3,3);
\coordinate (c2) at (5.5,1.5);
\coordinate (c3) at (8,4);
\coordinate (end) at (10.5,-0.8);
% show the points
\foreach \n in {start,c1,c2,c3,end} \fill [black] (\n)
    circle (2pt) node [below] {};
% join the coordinates
\draw [thick,name path=curve] (start) to[out=70,in=180] (c1) to[out=0,in=180]
    (c2) to[out=0,in=180] (c3) to[out=0,in=150] (end);
% add tangets and dashed lines
\foreach \c in {1,2,3} {
    %\draw [dashed] let \p1=(c\c) in (c\c) -- (\x1,0) node [below] {$c_\c$};
    \draw ($(c\c)-(0.75,0)$) -- ($(c\c)+(0.75,0)$) node [midway,above=4mm]{$$}; %{$f'(c_\c)=0$};
}
% add a and b
\path [name intersections={of={x and curve}, by={a,b}}] 
    (a) node [below left] {$a$}
    (b) node [above right] {$b$};
    
\DrawTangent[red, thick]{curve}{-1}{4}{1.5}
\DrawTangent[orange, thick]{curve}{-1}{4}{3.5}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I really like this answer plus the macro. I will allow other some time for others answer as well but this is what I was looking for!

Comment: Hi Peter if I were to name the curve by \draw[domain=.5:3.25,smooth,variable=\x,black,<->,thick] plot ({\x},{.5*(\x-1.5)*(\x-1.5)+1}); how would the syntax change>

Comment: @MathScholar: You need to use `name path=xxxx` to _name_ the curve (`xxxx` in this example), and pass that to `\DrawTangent[<draw options>]{xxxx}{<ymin>}{<ymax>}{x}`.

Comment: Yes I did that and got a horizontal line. I ask as a question as well so you can see the result and program. I thought this would be more easy to do! Here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/462070/tangents-to-general-curves

Comment: Sorry Peter I made a mistake! I got it! I deleted he question

Answer (score 15):

A PSTricks solution just for comparison purpose.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add,pst-vehicle,tikzducks}

\def\V{\rput(1,1.5){\psscalebox{-2 2}{\tikz{\duck[alien=red]}}}}
\def\F{2*cos(x)+x/3}
\def\Fp{Derive(1,\F)}

\def\tangent#1#2#3{\psplotTangent[linecolor=blue,showpoints]{#1}{.5}{\F}\uput[#2](*#1 {\F}){\scriptsize$f'#30$}}
\def\normal#1{\psplotTangent[linecolor=magenta,Derive={-1/\Fp},showpoints]{#1}{.2}{\F}}

\psset{plotpoints=200}
\begin{document}
\foreach \i in {-0.8,-0.6,...,10.8}{
\begin{pspicture}(-2.5,-2)(12.5,6)
    \psaxes[ticks=none,labels=none,linecolor=gray]{->}(0,0)(-2,-1.5)(11.5,5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]   
    \psplot[linecolor=red]{-1.5}{11}{\F}
        \normal{-1.5}
        \tangent{-1}{180}{>}
        \tangent{0.167}{-90}{=}
        \tangent{1.334}{0}{<}
        \tangent{2.974}{-90}{=}
        \tangent{4.7115}{0}{>}
        \tangent{6.449}{-90}{=}
        \tangent{7.852}{0}{<}
        \tangent{9.256}{-90}{=}
        \tangent{10.5}{0}{>}
        \normal{11}
    \psVehicle[vehicle=\SelfDefinedVehicle,ownvehicle=\V,showSlope=false,frontwheel=\SpokesWheelB,backwheel=\SpokesWheelA,rB=1.2,rF=0.9,d=3]{.2}{\i}{\F}        
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many compliments for your answer. +1.

Comment: This looks good but I am searching for an answer using using TiKz. Thanks AS!

Comment: Well, this is certainly nice but of course here you have an analytic expression for the curve. If you have this analytic expression, it is well known how to find the local extremal and tangents and all that, see e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46182/121799). I thought the challenge here was to do that to curves for which the analytic expression is not known. (This is not to criticize you, just to let you know that there exists quite some literature on this topic on this site.)

Comment: @marmot: Analytic expression is no longer as complicated as the previous one.

Comment: I presume if the "roller coaster" figure here were done instead with `tikz`, then the creature riding in the car would be a duck??

Comment: Don't forget that the wheels are rolling without slipping.

Answer (score 7):

This is just for fun and not to "steal" the check mark from Peter Grill, who IMHO should get it. Conceptually it is basically the same as [Jake's pioneering answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25928/how-to-draw-tangent-line-of-an-arbitrary-point-on-a-path-in-tikz/25940#25940). This answer comes with two styles: `tangent at` and `normal at`, which you can pass to the curve, and utilizes `decorations.markings` rather than `intersections`. If you want to draw several tangents and/or normals, it is advantageous to use `/.list`, as in the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{tikz/.cd,
tangent length/.store in=\TangentLength,
tangent length=7mm,
normal length/.store in=\NormalLength,
normal length=7mm}
\tikzset{tangent/.style={red,thin},normal/.style={blue,thin},
tangent at/.style={postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,
mark=at position #1 with {\draw[tangent] (-\TangentLength,0) -- (\TangentLength,0);
\fill[tangent] (0,0) circle (2pt);}}}},
normal at/.style={postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,
mark=at position #1 with {\draw[normal] (0,-\NormalLength) -- (0,\NormalLength);
\fill[normal] (0,0) circle (2pt);}}}},
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% Axes
\draw [-latex] (-1,0) -- (11,0) node [right] {$x$};
\draw [-latex] (0,-1) -- (0,6) node [above] {$y$};
% Origin
\node at (0,0) [below left] {$0$};
% Points
\coordinate (start) at (1,-0.8);
\coordinate (c1) at (3,3);
\coordinate (c2) at (5.5,1.5);
\coordinate (c3) at (8,4);
\coordinate (end) at (10.5,-0.8);
% show the points
% \foreach \n in {start,c1,c2,c3,end} \fill [black] (\n)
%     circle (2pt) node [below] {};
% join the coordinates
\draw [thick,tangent at/.list={0.15,0.3,...,0.75},
normal at/.list={0.25,0.4,...,0.7}] (start) to[out=70,in=180] (c1) to[out=0,in=180]
    (c2) to[out=0,in=180] (c3) to[out=0,in=150] (end);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Just if you are wondering: yes, it is possible to draw the tangent at some specific point the curve runs through. One possibility is to use the tricks of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/461398/121799), i.e. decompose the path into segments and attach the tangents/normals to the starting or end points of those. If you want to have this spelled out, please ask a new question, this here is really just for fun.

**ADDENDUM**: As for your request in the comments... (and yes, I am using Jake's answer, as I mention above)....

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,intersections}

\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{tikz/.cd,
tangent length/.store in=\TangentLength,
tangent length=3.14cm,
normal length/.store in=\NormalLength,
normal length=7mm}
\newcounter{tangent}
\newcounter{normal}
\tikzset{tangent/.style={red,thin},normal/.style={blue,thin},
tangent at/.style={postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,
mark=at position #1 with {\stepcounter{tangent}
\draw[tangent,name path=tangent-\thetangent] (-\TangentLength,0) -- (\TangentLength,0);
\fill[tangent] (0,0) circle (2pt);}}}},
normal at/.style={postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,
mark=at position #1 with {\stepcounter{normal}
\draw[normal,name path=normal-\thenormal] (0,-\NormalLength) -- (0,\NormalLength);
\fill[normal] (0,0) circle (2pt);}}}},
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% Axes
\draw [-latex] (-1,0) -- (11,0) node [right] {$x$};
\draw [-latex] (0,-1) -- (0,6) node [above] {$y$};
% Origin
\node at (0,0) [below left] {$0$};
% Points
\coordinate (start) at (1,-0.8);
\coordinate (c1) at (3,3);
\coordinate (c2) at (5.5,1.5);
\coordinate (c3) at (8,4);
\coordinate (end) at (10.5,-0.8);
% show the points
% \foreach \n in {start,c1,c2,c3,end} \fill [black] (\n)
%     circle (2pt) node [below] {};
% join the coordinates
\draw [name path=curve,thick,tangent at/.list={0.15,0.3,...,0.75},
normal at/.list={0.25,0.4,...,0.7}] (start) to[out=70,in=180] (c1) to[out=0,in=180]
    (c2) to[out=0,in=180] (c3) to[out=0,in=150] (end);
\fill[name intersections={of=curve and tangent-2,total=\t},cyan]
(intersection-\t) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this looks fantastic as well and uses  methods from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25928/how-to-draw-tangent-line-of-an-arbitrary-point-on-a-path-in-tikz/25940#25940 I believe. How can I extend the second tangent starting from the left and use the intersection, calc package to show where it intersects the curve further towards the right?

Comment: @MathScholar I added something. (I guess on the long run one may have to look at the internals of the `intersections` and `fillbetween` libraries, which internally compute all sorts of of useful quantities like `\pgfintersectiongetsolutiontimes`, which however did not make it to the manual.)

Comment: per your request I will give the check to Peter. Both posts are extremely helpful. Thanks Marmot!

Comment: @MathScholar Thanks! (I generally do not like if a question that has already an answer that is to the point gets a second answer, which is not to the point or just merely a repetition, like e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/461612/use-foreach-statement-to-simplify-tikz-drawing). This brings unnecessary tension between the users IMHO, and the last thing I want to do is to step others on the feet.)

Comment: @Hi Marmot, if I continue to extend the tangent to the right and fix the left side, there will be another intersection of the curve and tangent. Why does the intersection not get detected by the program?

Comment: @MathScholar I don't know (without a code). Please ask a new question with the code.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a macro inspired by @PeterGrill's answer in which I tried to automate the calculations. This macro is called `\secante` because it allows you to draw both a **tangent** and a **normal** to the curve.

To draw the two vertical lines, I drew these vertical lines using the current bounding box, which avoids manual calculations.

[image: bounding-box]

This allows me to add parameters such as the **length** and its **angle** with the tangent.

```
  % #1 = draw options
  % #2 = name of curve
  % #3 = x value at which tangent is to be drawn
  % #4 = length of the tangent (approximation)
  % #5 = angle with tangent,0 by default, 90 for normal
```

[image: rotate]

[image: tangente-normale]

The macro first determines the points where the verticals intersect with the curve. They are shown below in blue. The two points adjacent to the tangent contact point are called "gauche of curve" and "droite of curve".

[image: definitions-points]

This being done, with the `calc` library, the contact point is projected orthogonally on the segment `(gauche of curve)--(droite of curve)`

Then, we make a translation, of these points to find the two end points of this tangent.

It is then enlarged.

[image: exemple]

Here is an example produced by the code below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,arrows.meta}
\newcommand{\secante}[5][]{
\tikzset{every node/.style={font=\scriptsize}}
  % #1 = draw options
  % #2 = name of curve
  % #3 = x value at which tangent is to be drawn
  % #4 = length of the tangent (approximation)
  % #5 = angle avec la tangente,0 par défaut, 90 pour la normale
\path[name path=verticale] (current bounding box.south west -|#3,0)--(#3,0 |-current bounding box.north east);
\path[name path=gauche] (current bounding box.south west -|#3-.01,0)--(#3-.01,0 |-current bounding box.north east);
\path[name path=droite] (current bounding box.south west -|#3+.01,0)--(#3+.01,0 |-current bounding box.north east);
% point de contact de la tangente
\path [name intersections={of= verticale and #2,by=point of tangency}];
% points d'approximation de la sécante (parallèle)
\path [name intersections={of= gauche and #2,by=gauche of #2}];
\path [name intersections={of= droite and #2,by=droite of #2}];
% projection du point de contact sur la parallèle
\coordinate(projection) at ($(gauche of #2)!(point of tangency)!(droite of #2)$);
% points de la sécante
\coordinate(gauche of secant line) at ($(gauche of #2)+(point of tangency)-(projection)$);
\coordinate(droite of secant line) at ($(droite of #2)+(point of tangency)-(projection)$);
% secant ou normale
\draw[#1]($(gauche of secant line)!#4/2!#5:(droite of secant line)$)--($(droite of secant line)!#4/2!#5:(gauche of secant line)$);
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% Axes
\draw [->, name path=x] (-1,0) -- (11,0) node [right] {$x$};
\draw [->] (0,-1) -- (0,6) node [above] {$y$};
% Origin
\node at (0,0) [below left] {$0$};
% Points
\coordinate (start) at (1,-0.8);
\coordinate (c1) at (3,3);
\coordinate (c2) at (5.5,1.5);
\coordinate (c3) at (8,4);
\coordinate (end) at (10.5,-0.8);
% show the points
\foreach \n in {start,c1,c2,c3,end} \fill [black] (\n)
    circle (2pt) node [below] {};
%% join the coordinates
\draw [semithick,name path=curve] (start) to[out=70,in=180] (c1) to[out=0,in=180]
    (c2) to[out=0,in=180] (c3) to[out=0,in=150] (end);

\secante[red,thick]{curve}{3}{2cm}{0}
\secante[red,thick]{curve}{3}{2cm}{0} % tangent to the curve
\secante[red,thick]{curve}{5}{2cm}{0}
\secante[red,thick]{curve}{7}{2cm}{0}
\secante[red,thick]{curve}{9}{2cm}{0}
\secante[blue,thick]{curve}{8}{1cm}{90}
\secante[blue,thick]{curve}{10}{1cm}{90} % normal to the curve
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator

Comment: Thanks Andre' I understand some of the French words in the program and like the animation as well.

Comment: @MathScholar Do I have to translate the code comments into English?

Comment: No I understand everything. I studied French in Paris for several months!

Comment: +1 How can this answer only have one upvote! :)

Answer (score 1):

Using the [`tzplot`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tzplot) package:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
    
\usepackage{tzplot}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tzhelplines(-1,-1)(11,6)
\tzaxes*(-1,-1)(11,6){$x$}{$f(x)$}
\tzcoors*(1,-.8)(start)(3,3)(c1)(5.5,1.5)(c2)(8,4)(c3)(10.5,-.8)(end);
\tztos[thick]"curve"(start)[out=70,in=180](c1)[out=0,in=180]
                    (c2)[out=0,in=180](c3)[out=0,in=150](end);
\tztangent{curve}(c1)[2:4]
\tztangent{curve}(c2)[4.5:6.5]
\tztangent{curve}(c3)[7:9.5]{$f'(x)=0$}[r]
\tzslopeat[red,<->]{curve}{8}{2cm}[90]
\tztangentat[red]{curve}{2}[1:4]{$f'(x)$}[r]
\tzsecantat[blue]{curve}{5.5}{6.3}
\tzsecantat[blue]{curve}{5.5}{6.5}
\tzsecantat[blue]{curve}{5.5}{6.7}
\tzsecantat[blue]{curve}{5.5}{6.9}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```