# Use a foreach statement to simplify TikZ drawing

Tags: tikz-pgf

Below, the two diagrams should be the same, but actually they are not!

```
\documentclass[margin=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}
\newcommand{\PL}[3][]{
    \node[thick,circle,draw,minimum size=0.5cm,inner sep=0,outer sep=0,label=left:#3,#1](#2){};
    \draw[thick,#1] (#2.south west) -- (#2.north east);
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \PL{L1}{1}
    \PL[below=0.1 of L1]{L2}{2}
    \PL[below=0.1 of L2]{L3}{3}
    \PL[below=0.1 of L3]{L4}{4}
    \PL[below=0.1 of L4]{L5}{5}
    \PL[below=0.1 of L5]{L6}{6}
    \PL[below=0.1 of L6]{L7}{7}
    \node[fit=(L1)(L7), draw] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \PL{L1}{1}
    \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \j using \i - 1] in {2,...,7} {
        \PL[below=0.1cm of L\j]{L\i}{\i}
    }
    \node[fit=(L1)(L7), draw] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How do I fix the `\foreach` statement diagram?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you do not evaluate `\j` to an integer, you get numbers like `1.0`, in which `.0` is interpreted as the east anchor. So all I did was to replace `[evaluate=\i as \j using \i - 1]` by `[evaluate=\i as \j using {int(\i - 1)}]` to get

```
\documentclass[margin=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}
\newcommand{\PL}[3][]{
    \node[thick,circle,draw,minimum size=0.5cm,inner sep=0,outer sep=0,label=left:#3,#1](#2){};
    \draw[thick,#1] (#2.south west) -- (#2.north east);
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \PL{L1}{1}
    \PL[below=0.1 of L1]{L2}{2}
    \PL[below=0.1 of L2]{L3}{3}
    \PL[below=0.1 of L3]{L4}{C}
    \PL[below=0.1 of L4]{L5}{R}
    \PL[below=0.1 of L5]{L6}{RC}
    \PL[below=0.1 of L6]{L7}{RH}
    \node[fit=(L1)(L7), draw] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \PL{L1}{1}
    \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \j using {int(\i - 1)}] in {2,...,7} {
        \PL[below=0.1cm of L\j]{L\i}{\i}
    }
    \node[fit=(L1)(L7), draw] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**: Since @AndréC added an answer which is IMHO not really to the point of the original question, I add something that is to the point of the original question as well as some sort of a response to AndréC.

1. You can avoid all this by using `remember...`. And you can, of course, attach the labels of your left diagram, just declare `\i` to be the count.
2. Using a path picture to strike out a node is one way, what you are doing is IMHO at least equally good, and one can also use `strike out` that comes with `shapes.misc`. None of this, however, is IMHO at the heart of the question.

So here is an example (but if I was you I would keep your way of striking the node out, probably using a `path picture` is more elegant than `strike through`, though).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,shapes.misc}
\newcommand{\PL}[3][]{
    \node[thick,strike out,
    draw,minimum size=0.35cm,inner sep=0,outer sep=0,#1](#2-inner){};
    \node[draw,circle,inner sep=0,fit=(#2-inner),outer sep=1pt,label=left:#3](#2){};
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \PL{L1}{1}
    \foreach \X [count=\i starting from 2,remember=\i as \j (initially 1)] 
    in {2,3,C,R,RC,RH} {
        \PL[below=0.1cm of L\j]{L\i}{\X}
    }
    \node[fit=(L1)(L7), draw] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, It's so hard to figure it out by me :-).

Comment: @lucky1928 There are several variants of this question on this site, meaning that this is somewhat tricky and has been overlooked by several. (One way to figure out what's going on is to add `\typeout`s to your code, so if you add `\typeout{\j}` to your code you will see `1.0`, `2.0` and so on, which may help to get on track.)

Comment: Your explanation of the problem is wonderful.I never thought it was just a problem with the interpretation of writing `1.0`. Congratulations!

Answer (score 5):

It is not necessary to use a `LaTeX` command to trace nodes. All you have to do is declare tikz `styles`. 
To draw the diagonal bar, I used the notion of `path picture bounding box` described on page 173 of the 3.0.1a manual.

[image: style]

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}
%\newcommand{\PL}[3][]{
%    \node[thick,circle,draw,minimum size=0.5cm,inner sep=0,outer sep=0,label=left:#3,#1](#2){};
%    \draw[thick,#1] (#2.south west) -- (#2.north east);
%}

\begin{document}
%    \begin{tikzpicture}
%    \PL{L1}{1}
%    \PL[below=0.1 of L1]{L2}{2}
%    \PL[below=0.1 of L2]{L3}{3}
%    \PL[below=0.1 of L3]{L4}{4}
%    \PL[below=0.1 of L4]{L5}{5}
%    \PL[below=0.1 of L5]{L6}{6}
%    \PL[below=0.1 of L6]{L7}{7}
%    \node[fit=(L1)(L7), draw] {};
%\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    [slash/.style={
        draw,thick,circle,minimum size=.5cm,
        inner sep =0pt,outer sep=0pt,
        label={left:#1},
        path picture={
            \draw(path picture bounding box.south west)--(path picture bounding box.north east);}
    }]
    \node[slash=1](L1){};
    \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \j using int(\i - 1)] in {2,...,7} {
        \node[below=0.1 of L\j,slash=\i](L\i){};
    }
    \node[fit=(L1)(L7), draw] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Update (to answer to marmot):

@marmot: I know for a fact that my answer is not the heart of the question. And that was not my point.

To simplify even more the loop:

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    [slash/.style={
        draw,thick,circle,minimum size=.5cm,
        inner sep =0pt,outer sep=0pt,
        label={left:#1},
        path picture={
            \draw(path picture bounding box.south west)--(path picture bounding box.north east);}
    }]
    \node[slash=1](L1){};
    \foreach \j [count=\i] in {2,...,7} {
        \node[below=0.1 of L\i,slash=\j](L\j){};
    }
    \node[fit=(L1)(L7), draw] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for the use of `path picture` (even though I do not think that this is at the heart of the question).